# selecting data where column='null'

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I want to query data and the column (Continent) either has a value of 'Africa' or Null.

I want to use this column name in my query but for the countries where the name is not Africa I get no data.

This is what I have tried but returns no data.

```
SqlDataAdapter dba = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * from [tblCountries] 
                     WHERE [Continent] = '' order by [Common Name]", connection);
                    //WHERE [Continent]<>'Africa' order by [Common Name]", connection);
                   //WHERE [Continent] IS null order by [Common Name]", connection);
dba.Fill(ds);

drpNonAfricanCountries.DataSource = ds;
```

What would be the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
SqlDataAdapter dba = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * from [tblCountries] 
                                     WHERE [Continent] IS NULL order by [Common Name]", connection);
            dba.Fill(ds);
            drpNonAfricanCountries.DataSource = ds;
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to query data and the column (Continent) either has a value of
>   'Africa' or Null.

```
WHERE [Continent] = 'Africa' OR  [Continent] IS NULL
```

For comparing a column with `NULL` use `IS NULL`

So your final code should be:

```
SqlDataAdapter dba = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * from [tblCountries] 
               WHERE [Continent] = 'Africa' OR  [Continent] IS NULL order by [Common Name]", connection);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from tblCountries where (Continent = 'Africa' or Continent is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

SELECT * from [tblCountries] WHERE [Continent] IS NULL OR [Continent]= 'Africa' order by [Common Name];